# Render Times progressively becoming longer with each frame

Tags: rendering, animation

I'm rendering a bottle falling into a cloth simulation with depth of field and a bit of motion blur turned on.

When hit f12 ctrl and render the first frame is about 1 minute, the 2nd will be 1:30, the third maybe 2 minutes, and when I check a couple frames later and it is rendering at 5-6 minutes per frame. No big changes in the animation or movement are happening, no extra objects or lights are coming through, its the same set up consistently throughout the animation. It doesnt matter where I stop rendering the frames, if I abort the final 5 minute renders and just try again on the very same frame a minute later, it will render in 1 minute.

Why is it slowing down so much in animations?

Comment: Have you tried checking Persistent Data on the Render Properties tab under Performance > Final Render?

Comment: have you tried batch rendering? which is "normally" quicker anyway. I can recommend using loom (free add-on) which supports that by just one shortcut